# Oracle OCI Function - Config file not accessible

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Hello stackoverflow people!

I’m deploying a java function with Oracle cloud Shell.

I made all necessary configurations :

- user creation
- api token creation
- check if ~/.oci/config file is properly created (with DEFAULT settings)

After that I deployed my Java function on a docker container with the command.

```
fn deploy —-app <app name>
```

Then I called my function:

```
fn invoke <app name> <function name>
```

The goal of my function is to update my Load Balancer RuleSet.

Finally I had an error message :

```
Error 502 : FunctionInvokeExecutionError
```

Not a lot of traces available, but I identified that the following code was on error.

```
  final ConfigFileReader.ConfigFile configFile = 
                    ConfigFileReader.parse(“~/.oci/config“, “DEFAULT“);
```

The folder and the config file are not accessible by the function.

I tried to replace the config file by a new one generated with the command line

```
oci setup config
```

I tried to test the function in local (with the config file in local as well) => it works.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to interact with OCI resources from the function execution environment, you should consider using Resource Principal authorization as you are not including `~/.oci/config` in the container.

https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/instance-and-resource-principal-authentication-with-the-oci-typescriptjavascript-sdk

Note that you need to create a dynamic policy and a policy to allow the function to manage the LoadBalancers in tenancy/compartment: https://redthunder.blog/2020/09/21/secure-inter-service-communication-in-oci/

Here is an example using Resource Principal in Java:
https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/FunctionsEphemeralResourcePrincipalAuthenticationDetailsProviderExample.java